# Passing array of structure to fread and fwrite function in C

Tags: c

I have a questions regarding the `fread()` and `fwrite()` function in c.

Talking about the first parameter `void*` If i am dealing with array of structure and want to pass an entire array what should i use `&arrayName` or `arrayName`.

Now I am trying to input some data from users create a `student.txt` file and store the data in that file and again read that data from the same file and display it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
struct dob
{
    int year,month,date;
};

struct student
{
    int roll;
    char name[20],address[20],faculty[30];
    struct dob a;
};
struct student s1[2],s2[2];
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("student.txt","w+b");
if(fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Cannot open file");
    exit(0);
}
 for(int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
 {
     fflush(stdin);
     printf("Enter the name of student %d\n",i+1);
     scanf("%[^\n]s",s1[i].name);
     fflush(stdin);
     printf("Enter address\n");
     scanf("%[^\n]s",s1[i].address);
     fflush(stdin);
     printf("Enter roll no\n");
     scanf("%d",&s1[i].roll);
     fflush(stdin);
     printf("Enter faculty\n");
     scanf("%[^\n]s",s1[i].faculty);
     fflush(stdin);
     printf("Enter the Birth year\n");
     scanf("%d",&s1[i].a.year);
     printf("Enter the Birth month\n");
     scanf("%d",&s1[i].a.month);
     printf("Enter the Birth date\n");
     scanf("%d",&s1[i].a.date);
 }
 fwrite(&s1,sizeof(s1),2,fp);
 rewind(fp);
 fread(&s2,sizeof(s2),2,fp);
 for(int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
 {
     printf("Name : %s\n Address = %s\n Faculty = %s\n Roll = %d\n year = %d\n month = %d\n date = 
    %d\n",
   s2[i].name,s2[i].address,s2[i].faculty,s2[i].roll,s2[i].a.year,s2[i].a.month,s2[i].a.date);
 }
 
fclose(fp);
return 0;
 }
```

I am asking it because both of them works for my above code.But How?
I am talking about this line

```
 fwrite(&s1,sizeof(s1),2,fp);
 fread(&s2,sizeof(s2),2,fp);
```

Here s1 and s2 works without `&` as well

Comment: `s1` and `&s1` are the same thing.

Comment: Note that `"%[^\n]s"` is your hybrid of `"%s"` and `"%[^\n]"`

Comment: @ScottHunter isn't `&s1` a pointer with the address of `s1`?

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined for an input stream. To get rid of the newline left by "%[^\n]" add a space before the `%` in the following `scanf()`, for example `scanf(" %d", &s1[i].roll);`

Comment: @WeatherVane if i am dealing with array how can input strings with space then?

Comment: @Davide Indeed. The expressions `s1` and `&s1` are different *types*. The former converts to a temporary `struct student*`, the latter converts to `struct student (*)[2]`. It would have been more accurate had scott said "evaluate to the same *address* , which , in this specific usage context, is all that really matters as the first argument to a function expecting `void *`. It matters a great deal more in other contexts, particularly ones involving pointer arithmetic.

Comment: By using `" %[^\n]"`